# There's a problem about using double and im stucked somewhere?

Tags: c#, mysql, integer, double

I wanna add 0.50 to an integer just im confused. I dont know how to do. 
There's the code;

```
if (checkBox1.Checked)
{
    keko.Open();

    double mesai = Convert.ToDouble(textBox4.Text);
    mesai = mesai + 0.50;
    double maaş = Convert.ToDouble(textBox4.Text);
    maaş += 1;
    textBox4.Text = mesai.ToString() + maaş.ToString();

    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(
      "Update calisanlist Set Gun '" + textBox4.Text + "' where (Adı,Soyadı) '" + textBox1.Text + "','"+textBox2.Text+"'", 
       keko);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    keko.Close();
```

There's a checkbox under the button. If i press the button without check the box, It adds itself 1 okay there's no problem here. But, When i check the box and Press the button i have an error message.

`MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException`:

> 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''7,58' where (Adı,Soyadı) 'Egemen','Ören'' at line 1'.

I dont know how to solve it please help me

Comment: Use parameters in your SQL statement and `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue` to add their values to the command. Not only does this prevent SQL injection, it will avoid the culture-sensitive formatting issue you're encountering. Finally, your SQL seems to have a number of syntax errors in it; try getting the statement right in MySQL Workbench before copying it into your C# code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, that you may well have a problem in

```
   textBox4.Text = mesai.ToString() + maaş.ToString();
```

Imagine, that `mesai` is `3.5` when `maaş` is `4.1`: you'll have `3.54.1` in the `textBox4.Text` which is not a *valid* `double` value.
You probably mean

```
   double mesai = Convert.ToDouble(textBox4.Text) + 0.5;
   //TODO: check isn't it a typo? Both mesai and maaş are from the same textBox4.Text
   double maaş = Convert.ToDouble(textBox4.Text) + 1;

   textBox4.Text = (mesai + maaş).ToString();
```

Do not *hardcode* query, but *parametrize* it

```
   ... 

   // Keep sql readable
   // and parameterized
   string sql = 
     @"update calisanlist
          set Gun = @prm_Gun
        where Adı = @prm_Adi and
              Soyadı = @prm_Soyadı";  

   // wrap IDisposable into "using"
   using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, keko)) {
     // I don't know underlying database types, that's why I've put AddWithValue
     //TODO: change syntax to cmd.Parameters.Add(name, datatype).Value = ...
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm_Gun", Convert.ToDouble(textBox4.Text));
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm_Adi", textBox1.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm_Soyadı", textBox2.Text); 

     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   } 
   ...
```